# How to disable a class API when the class cannot operate under some conditions?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, factory

Say I have the following:

```
class Processor
{
public:
    void Activate();
    /* some more interface functions*/
};

void main()
{
    Processor().Activate();
}
```

class `Processor` is just an example of any class that provides public interface.

#### Problem

What if class `Processor` is **only** operational iff some conditions are met. Just for example, class `Processor` is preforming some file system operations on a directory `X` and if the directory `X` does not exist it can't operate at all.

#### Issue

Who is responsible to validate the conditions are met and the class is operational?

---

Let's encapsulate evaluating those conditions to one logic function called `Enabled()`

#### Suggestion 1 - Caller responsibility

```
void main()
{
    if (Enabled() )
        Processor().Activate();
}
```

In this case, initiator of class `Processor` is responsible to make sure these condition are met before initiating the class.

**Cons**

1. Caller may not know what are the condition
2. This doesn't resolve the bigger issue, what if we have other callers that don't verify the condition?

---

#### Suggestion 2 - Class responsibility

```
class Processor
{
public:

    Processor()
    {
        // init m_bIsEnabled based on conditions
    }

    void Activate()
    {
        if (!m_bIsEnabled)
            return;

        // do something
    }
    /* some more interface functions*/
private:
    bool m_bIsEnabled;
};
```

in this case, all public interface functions are disabled if class is not enabled.

**Cons**

1. What if class `Processor` has numerous interface function, do we check the value of `m_bIsEnabled` in the beginning of each function?
2. What if in the future some developer enhance the interface and forgets to check the value of `m_bIsEnabled`?
3. What are the default values returned in each functions in case `m_bIsEnabled == false`

---

#### Suggestion 3 - Factory

```
using Processor_ptr = shared_ptr < Processor > ;

class ProcessorFactory
{
    static Processor_ptr create()
    {
        Processor_ptr p;

        p.reset(new Processor);
        if (!p->IsEnabled())
            p.reset(nullptr);

        return p;
    }
};


class Processor
{
public:
    void Activate();
    bool IsEnabled();
    friend class ProcessorFactory;
private:
    Processor();
    bool m_bIsEnabled;
};
```

This method is so far my favorite since we prevent class generation if it cannot operate.

**Cons**
 1. Perhaps an overkill?

---

#### Question

Which of the suggestions is preferable in terms of best practice? do we have other suggestions?

Comment: I sort of like the one you call "factory" though I think it would be easier to use if you simply threw from the constructor if the class was not usable.  But if the class may be usable now but unusable later, or vice versa, then each method should check; if you care about efficiency then you might require the caller to check as in your first example, but add an `assert()` statement to make sure at the top of each method that it's valid (in debug builds).

Comment: For simplicity, let assume the if the class if unusable, then it remains in that state. Moreover, All functions are unusable all together (if the conditions are not met).

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for option number #3, as options #2 & #1 are hard to track and enforces the  developer to always validate the Active flag prior each function's execution. moreover, you can expand option #3 by return an empty object which implements the interface but actually does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a fan of #3 like igalk. But it worth mention that this is a typical situation for the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization).
You throw an exception when the condition of the instance creation is not met in your constructor:

```
class Processor
{
public:    
    Processor()
    {
        //  based on conditions
        if(!folderexist)  // pseudocode
          throw(cannotcreate)
    }

//    void Activate() not needed anymore

    /* some more interface functions*/
private:
//    bool m_bIsEnabled; not needed anymore
};
```

This is a common pattern in libs already using exceptions. I myself have no problems with exception as long as they are used in a proper way. Unfortunately I see often exceptions used as longjumps or as shortcuts to save some lines of code.
A fail can be a valid state of an instance. In this case IMHO it is better to create the instance and have a "valid" flag (case #2). But most time, the created object is worthless and the information of fail is only of interest for the creator. In this case RAII may be the better choice. The factory pattern avoid the exception in an elegant way if you do not want or cannot use exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, any or all of those strategies can be employed, depending on what code is able to detect the problem.

Generally, though, I would not encourage usage of an "enabled" or "valid state" flag in the object.   If a problem is detected, such a flag is an opportunity to continue despite the problem (e.g. forget to check the flag, forget to set the flag, inappropriately ignore the value of the flag).   Programmers are human and, as code gets more complicated, it becomes easier to make a mistake that is very hard to track down.

If the caller detects a problem then it should not create the object or (if the object already exists) it should destroy the object.  It can then give an indication to its caller of the problem.

If the object itself detects a problem, then it should recover as best as possible, and give an indication to the caller.

Either way, this means that, if the object exists, it remains in a valid state until a problem is detected, and detection of a problem will cause the object not to exist.

What indications need to be given depend on severity of the problem, but include various approaches between an error code (which can be ignored by the caller) and an exception (which must be handled, and the problem corrected, if the program is to continue).

BTW:  `main()` returns `int`, not `void`.